# Hi, could you please help me with the translation of these weapon parts?

Tags: translation, word-choice, vocabulary

Could you please check, if I have translated these sentences in a right way? Thanks a lot! :)

1. 气体调节器 - gas adjuster
2. 瞄准装置 - scope
3. 复进簧 - return spring
4. 活塞簧 - bolt spring
5. 上护盖 - upper cover
6. 活塞 - bolt
7. 机头 - action
8. 机体 - chamber
9. 枪托- stock
10. 弹匣- magazine

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect task for the English-Chinese translator. Watch out for regional differences in naming these parts.

Answer (score 1):

气体调节器 should be gas regulator, I don't think there is any such thing as a gas adjuster?

For 瞄准装置 you wrote scope but I don't see any scope in your photo, is it supposed to just be some type of sights?

复进簧 should be recoil spring, again I don't think a thing such as a return spring exists.

The literal translation of 活塞簧 is piston spring, I'm not sure if it should be translated differently from that since the word I know for bolt would be 栓 or 枪栓. Also the drawing looks more like for the piston, in which case I think carrier spring is the term in English.

上护盖 might be an upper guard but maybe a dust cover for a scope to go on? I don't recognize the Chinese term.  I think upper cover in English is probably not right, I'm not aware of such a term. The Chinese is as vague as the photo to me here.

See what I said before, trying to go off the drawing this 活塞 looks a lot more like its part of the piston set up.

The term I know for action is 枪机. 机头 I believe this is referring to the forend of the gun but I also don't think its the official term. The one I know for that 护木头. (机头 term is usually airplanes nose etc.)

膛室  is the term I know for chamber.  Maybe 机体 is referring to the frame in general, but the term I know for that is 枪身. Again the term you have here I know for planes etc.

枪托 is the butt of the gun, so stock is fine.

弹匣 is the ammo magazine, correct.

---

I said all this off of basic gun knowledge, but terms might vary. As with any technical knowledge, I highly recommend becoming familiar with the parts of the gun in question in your native language and then finding the name for that term in the other.  Guns vary a lot and a specific model may have a term others don't.

As it stands I'm not fully certain of the Chinese or the English here.  The photo that doesn't actually label or display all the gun parts does not help narrow things down.

Hope this helps, if you are able to specify the model of gun or find a better photo of what you want translated than a much more detailed answer can be given.

Comment: 瞄准装置 is the "aiming device", which can be a scope, but for this raffle, it consists of the two vertical pointing pieces on top of the barrel, one at the front, one at the back, when aligned with the goal, a line of sight is achieved.

Comment: 机头 is the front piece of the barrel, a removable part separated from the gun chamber (机体).

Comment: just to add that the "aiming device" being described are "iron sights" and there's a Chinese article on them with the relevant terminology linked from the relevant Wiki page.

Comment: @lly because all the different sights have their own names, I left it as a generic "sights".  Without clarification I thought that was best, to avoid giving a term that isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Better not refer to text,some name are wrong even in the picture.Such as the 气体调节器,I feel wired,may not it's real name.
Look for refer about QBZ-97 structure may easy on google.They are same to picture.

Answer (score -1):

### Note : 第五张图片很详细除了没有瞄准部分，基本上可以找到大部分你想要的武器零件的英文名称.

## 第一张图片

[image]

## 第二张图片

[image]

## 第三张图片

[image]

## 第四张图片

[image]

## 第五张图片

[image]

Above picture is AK Rifle Parts and Accessories.

## 第六张图片

[image]

从上面图片可以看到

`瞄准装置` 是 `scope` , from `第六张图片` .

`复进簧` (或 `复位弹簧`) 是 `return spring` , from `第五张图片` .

`上护盖` 是 `upper handguard` , from `第五张图片` or [AMD-65](https://wiki2.org/en/AMD-65) (if [AMD-65 website](https://wiki2.org/en/AMD-65)  can't open, see at [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919144723/https://wiki2.org/en/AMD-65)) .

`枪托` 是 `Buttstock` , 但也有叫 `stock`, from `第一张图片` or `第三张图片` or `第六张图片` .

`弹匣` 是 `Magazine` , from `第一张图片` or `第二张图片` or `第三张图片` or `第四张图片` .

`活塞` 是 `gas piston` . from `第五张图片` or [Short-stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-operated_reloading#Short-stroke), (if [Short-stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-operated_reloading#Short-stroke) can't open, see [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230522132902/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-operated_reloading))

从上面我发的图片可以很明显看到 `活塞不是bolt` . bolt是枪栓, see at [Bolt (firearms)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_(firearms)) or  [枪栓](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%9E%AA%E6%A0%93).

[image]